# SurveyMoneky request with curl

Tags: curl, surveymonkey

We are attempting to use the Survey Monkey API but are getting some odd results, when making a request through our app or with curl via command line:

```
curl -H 'Authorization:bearer XXXX' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/user/get_user_details?api_key=YYYY
```

We get the following response:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>302 Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>302 Found</h1>
  The resource was found at /v2/user/get_user_details/?api_key=YYYY;     
  you should be redirected automatically.
 </body>
</html>
```

So I've tried adding the -L paramter to my curl request so that it will follow redirects and get the following:

```
<h1>Service Requires SSL</h1>
```

Any ideas as to what we are doing wrong?

Comment: re: the SSL error, there's an issue with our redirect, it shouldn't be redirecting you to http, thanks for the heads-up.  It was just going to redirect you to a 404 though, you do need to change the request to a POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a GET request to hit the end point, you need to modify it to provide a POST request. If it gives you an invalid scheme error, give it an empty JSON object (ie {}) in the request.

Comment: Note I will check into the redirect and why it's not using SSL.